# Broadcast and Concat don't work in Akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to create a graph with a `Broadcast` and a `Concat` in Akka Stream, but the following code doesn't work. I want to know why it doesn't work.

```
  val src = Source(1 to 3)
  val sink = Sink.foreach(println)
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val concat = b.add(Concat[Int](2))

    src  ~> bcast ~> concat ~> sink
            bcast ~> concat

    ClosedShape
  }).run()
```

My expected output is

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

But, actually, nothing is outputted. I would like you to tell why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Broadcast can only work if its downstreams all have demand, and concat only demands from one upstream at a time (otherwise you'd want to have merge etc), and thus broadcast cannot broadcast anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcast can only work if its downstreams all have demand, and concat only demands from one upstream at a time (otherwise you'd want to have merge etc), and thus broadcast cannot broadcast anything.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me.